# Failing to delete rows from a linked table

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have problems deleting the rows from a table.

I have 2 tables with the following definition:

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS = "elements";
    public static final String KEY_ROWELEMENTID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_STUDYID = "idstudy";
    public static final String KEY_ELEMENTCODE = "code_element";
    public static final String KEY_ELEMENTNAME = "description_element";


private static final String DATABASE_TABLETIME = "times";
    public static final String KEY_ROWTIME = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ELEMENTID = "idelement";
    public static final String KEY_HOURDATE = "hour_date";
    public static final String KEY_OBSERVEDYTIME = "observedtime";
    public static final String KEY_OBSERVEDACTIVITY = "observedactivity";
```

both tables are related:

```
elements._id = times.idelement
```

I want to delete all rows in table "times" which has the "idstudy" from table "elements" that the user has selected:

For this I created the following function:

```
public void ResetDataStudies(String selectedid) {
  String querytimes = "DELETE FROM "
  + "times"
  + " WHERE "
  + "times.idelement"
  + " IN "
  + "(SELECT "
  + "elements._id"
  + " FROM "
  + "elements"
  + " WHERE "
  + "elements.idstudy = ?)";
  ourDatabase.rawQuery(querytimes, new String[] { selectedid });
}
```

I don't receive a specific error, but after executing it the data has not been deleted.

See below the data type:

```
db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + " (" +
                     KEY_ROWELEMENTID + " INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                     KEY_ELEMENTCODE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                     KEY_ELEMENTNAME + " TEXT, " +
                     KEY_STUDYID + " TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES " +  DATABASE_TABLEACOUNT + "("+ KEY_ROWSTUDYID +") ON DELETE CASCADE ");      

             db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLETIME + " (" +
                     KEY_ROWTIME + " INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                     KEY_HOURDATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                     KEY_OBSERVEDYTIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                     KEY_OBSERVEDACTIVITY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                     KEY_ELEMENTID + " TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES " +  DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS + "("+ KEY_ROWELEMENTID +") ON DELETE CASCADE ");
        }
```

I have updated my statements but now I receive an error while creating the tables:

error near cascade statement

Comment: The query looks. Show some example data, and the data type of every value.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table, the foreign key needs to be `ON DELETE CASCADE`. e.g.

```
 FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_ELEMENTID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLEELEMENTS+" ("+KEY_ROWELEMENTID+") ON DELETE CASCADE); "
```

You'll also have to tell SQLite to enforce foreign keys (otherwise they are ignored).

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html.